# How are characters encoded in stty's output?

Tags: character-encoding, stty

I ran `stty --all` on a terminal which had been reconfigured by a badly behaved process which exited before putting my terminal back to its original settings. Part of the output reads: `eol = M-^?;`. What is this encoding? What does that sequence of characters mean?

The man page has this elucidating remark, presumably for those who understand a-priori:

> In settings, CHAR is taken literally, or  coded  as in ^c, 0x37, 0177 or 127; special values ^- or undef used to disable special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `M-` means the high bit is set, so add "0x80" to the character encoding.

The `^?` means the "DEL" character so 0x7F.

Add the two together and we get 0xFF.

We can test this:

```
$ stty -a | grep -w eol | sed 's/.*; //'
eol = <undef>;

$ stty eol 0xff 

$ stty -a | grep -w eol | sed 's/.*; //'
eol = M-^?;
```

A full list of control characters and their caret notation is available [under the *Control code chart* section of the Wikipedia article on ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart).

Comment: May I ask how you knew this? Is there a manual for this kind of thing?

Comment: The high bit is sometimes called the "meta bit", and so that's why `M-`.  `^?` is a standard representation of the DEL character.  This notation is not uncommon and you may also see it elsewhere.

Comment: @VoidStar  `man ascii` shows the `^` (Ctrl) encodings. These are a single-bit flip in the second-highest bit (i.e. 0x40). So CR (0x0D, carriage-return) is normally shown as `^M`, where M is 0x4D. `?` is 0x3F, so `^?` is 0x7F, and `M-^?` is 0xFF -- it gets both transformations.

Comment: I have also added a link to Wikipedia's table of control codes.